# How to select an element whose ascendant is not a certain tag?

Tags: xpath

I'd like to select elements of `strong`. But I want to select the ones not in `h3`. Does anybody know how to do in `xpath`? Thanks.

```
<h3><sub><strong>abc</strong></sub></h3>
```

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Comment: Yes. It is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re looking for the [`ancestor::`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#axes) axis.

```
//strong[not(ancestor::h3)]
```